# Thymeleaf: Unencode or Encode URL on client

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf as the front end.

I have some menu categories in natural language that I display on a web page and pass to the server.

For example, I have a category of *"My favourite cats"*

The category is in a variable *${category.key}*

This category has a link;

```html
<a th:href="|http://myserver?selectedCategory=${category.key}|><span th:text=${category.key}></span></a>
```

- If I do not URLEncode  ${category.key} on the server, then when a
  user clicks the link, the selectedCategory parameter is null if there
  is a whitespace in the category string.
- If I encode the category string, the  selectedCategory parameter
  passes to the server fine BUT the link text appears as
  My+favourite+cats

I don't want two variables, one encoded, one not encoded.

How do I either encode or unencode ${category.key} as part of the Thymeleaf HTML compilation process?

Comment: I've never used thymeleaf, but I just googled "thymeleaf link syntax", clicked on the first link, and found the documentation: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html. That said, you should really have a key uniquely identifying the category, whatever the language is, and an internationalized label associated with that key.

Comment: yup, but not when working in natural language processing. Too cumbersome. But I think I have found the solution: th:text="${#strings.replace(category.key,'+',' ')}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@symbol is Server Context path in Thymeleaf. you use @symbol.

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/your server context path?selectedCategory=__${category.key}__}">
<span th:text="${category.key}"> </span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf will url encode strings if you build them with url syntax ([which was supplied in a comment above](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)).  For your example url, it should look like this -- using the `@` symbol instead of the `$`:

```
<a th:href="@{http://myserver(selectedCategory=${category.key})}" th:text="${category.key}" />
```

(Also, you don't need that extra span.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the @symbol is definitely the primary alternative. But just to note another option that may be of use on occasions:

The answer is to use the lesser know #strings functions to replace the '+' with ' '

In the link text, use

```
th:text="${#strings.replace(category.key,'+',' ')}"
```