# HTML form URL encoding links in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, x-www-form-urlencoded

This question is not about URI-encoding links in Thymeleaf, but about *URL-encoding links*, which is a different thing.

I'm using Thymeleaf with Spring MVC in Spring Boot. I know that I can URI-encode a link in Thymeleaf using `@{…}` syntax, as explained in [Thymeleaf: Unencode or Encode URL on client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44791068). However I would like to URL-encode links.

I have an HTML form that sends a query in the form `foo+bar` using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type, which I am referring to as "URL encoding" However Thymeleaf's `@{…}` syntax encodes link parameters using the *URI encoding* `foo%20bar`.

Normally the newer URI encoding would be preferred, but I have another page that uses old-school HTML forms, which invariably send form data using URL encoding.

Fortunately (in this case) Spring MVC seems to accept both the `foo+bar` and the `foo%bar` encodings, but I think being wishy-washy on the format is bad form (pun unintended). I'd like to make the site uniform, which will also help users in creating consistent bookmarks. (Maybe in the future I will decide to only accept one format for the links.)

How can I tell Thymeleaf to URL-encode links using the `foo+bar` form? I'd prefer not to use manual string replacement, but I could accept that as a last resort. (Following [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791433), I tried using `@{…#strings.replace(data,' ','+')}`, but the `@{…}` wound up URI-encoding the `+`, producing `foo%2Bbar`.)

Alternatively, is there a simple way to tell my HTML form to submit data using the `foo%20bar` form? (I tried using the Thymeleaf `@{…}` syntax in the form data, to preformat it before submission, but couldn't get it to work on non-link data; this left the spaces untouched, leaving them for the `<form>` to URL-encode them using `+`.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create URLs with the "foo+bar" style encoding for consistency with your older HTML forms, while Thymeleaf's @{...} syntax uses the newer "foo%20bar" style encoding.Thymeleaf's #strings utility object to perform the encoding in the desired format.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<!-- content -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- content -->
</body>
</html>

<a th:href="@{someUrl(param=${#strings.replace(uriEncodingParam, '+', '%2B')})}">Link</a>
```

replace someUrl with your actual URL and uriEncodingParam with the URI-encoded parameter.

Comment: I'm not understanding your example. It appears `param=${#strings.replace(uriEncodingParam, '+', '%2B')}` would convert a `uriEncodingParam` of `foo+bar` to appear in a link as `param=foo%2Bbar`. But I'm wanting to convert `foo bar` to appear in a link as `param=foo+bar`. Am I misinterpreting the code?

Comment: The example I provided would indeed result in foo%2Bbar instead of foo+bar.

If your intention is to convert foo bar to appear in a link as param=foo+bar, then using the "#strings.replace" approach won't work as intended, because Thymeleaf's @{...} syntax will still perform URI encoding.

Guess you might need to manually construct the URLs with the appropriate encoding:)